# break in for loop python program

Tags: python

i try to make program if sum of program 1000 the program wil print finished but if the number when we input = 0 the program return error. i try it with break  in python but i dont get the right output. i need your oppinion about this.

```
this my program
banyak = int(input('Masukan banyak angka yang ingin dimasukkan = '))
for j in range(banyak):
    A = int(input("enter the number of 1 : "))
    B = int(input("enter the number of 2 : "))
    C = int(input("enter the number  of 3 : "))
    if(A + B + C == 1000):
        print("finished")
        break
    elif(A==0 or B==0 or C==0):
        print("error")
        break
```

the program should
input :

```
100
0
```

output:

```
error
```

input:

```
400
300
300
```

output:

```
finished
```

Comment: Please explain where the actual input is different of the expected output. For first input you give a 0 so get error, for second it sums at 1000 so you're ok, seems good to me

Comment: Is it the use of `break` that stops the loop that bother you ? If you specify a number of round to "play", you may NOT use a break, that stops the loop

Comment: if i input  A =100 B = 0 C = 300 my program keep running until finish ask input form user. and what i want is if i input A =100 and B = 0 the program stop and does'nt ask input C again.  so are if i input A = 0 the program stop and print error and doesnt ask input B and C again

Comment: Program stop OR only current iteration ? Does the game continue after printing error ?

Comment: no the program stop

Comment: And when you have good sum  program stops too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to use an `assert` statement after each input, if it is incorrect, it'll raise an `AssertionError` that you can catch. The second element for `assert` is the exeception message, that can be use in the `except` section

```
banyak = int(input('Masukan banyak angka yang ingin dimasukkan = '))
for j in range(banyak):
    print(f"Round {j + 1}/{banyak}")
    try:
        A = int(input("enter the number of 1 : "))
        assert A != 0, "A is 0"
        B = int(input("enter the number of 2 : "))
        assert B != 0, "B is 0"
        C = int(input("enter the number  of 3 : "))
        assert C != 0, "C is 0"
        if A + B + C == 1000:
            print("finished")
            break
    except AssertionError as e:
        print("Error:", e)
        break
```

---

```
Masukan banyak angka yang ingin dimasukkan = 5
Round 1/5
enter the number of 1 : 200
enter the number of 2 : 300
enter the number  of 3 : 100
Round 2/5
enter the number of 1 : 400
enter the number of 2 : 0
Error: B is 0
```

Comment: thank you. can i have any question about another program that i made. if you want to help me, let's start the discussion in the discussion chat.

Answer (score 0):

when you input

```sh
1    # banyak
100  # A
0    # B
```

then the program's current line is

```py
    C = int(input("enter the number  of 3 : "))
```

so it can't break. you can try this

```py
banyak = int(input('Masukan banyak angka yang ingin dimasukkan = '))

for j in range(banyak):
    A = int(input("enter the number of 1 : "))
    if A == 0:
        print("error")

    B = int(input("enter the number of 2 : "))
    if B == 0:
        print("error")

    C = int(input("enter the number  of 3 : "))
    if C == 0:
        print("error")


    if A + B + C == 1000:
        print("finished")
        break
```

but is so foolish. And you can try this

```py
banyak = int(input('Masukan banyak angka yang ingin dimasukkan = '))

for j in range(banyak):

    number_list = []
    for _ in range(3):
        input_number = int(input("enter the number : "))
        if input_number == 0:
            print("error")
            break
        number_list.append(input_number)


    if sum(number_list) == 1000:
        print("finished")
        break

    print('=============')
```

Comment: thank you. can i have any question about another program that i made. if you want to help me, let's start the discussion in the discussion chat?